# Couldn't match expected type in Pack function

Tags: haskell

I'm working through 99 Problems in Haskell and running into a type issue I cannot resolve.  I was using a wrapper function to solve the problem on my first attempt.

### The goal

Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists. If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.

### Example:

```
Main> pack ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
["aaaa","b","cc","aa","d","eeee"]
```

### My code:

```
pack :: (Eq(a)) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack xs = pack' ((filter (== head xs) xs):[]) (filter (/= head xs) xs)

pack' :: (Eq(a)) => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
pack' xs [] = xs
pack' xs ys = ((filter (== head ys) ys):xs) (filter (/= head ys) ys)
```

So when I run this, I have trouble with the 7th line and get the following debugger output:

```
09.hs:7:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0] -> [[a]]'
                 with actual type `[[a]]'
    The function `(filter (== head ys) ys) : xs'
    is applied to one argument,
    but its type `[[a]]' has none
    In the expression: ((filter (== head ys) ys) : xs) (filter (/= head ys) ys)
    In an equation for pack':
        pack' xs ys = ((filter (== head ys) ys) : xs) (filter (/= head ys) ys)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I just do not see where the extra [a0] -> [[a]] is coming from.

```
Prelude> let b = [5,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,5,6]
Prelude> (filter (== head b) b):[]
[[5,5,5]]
Prelude> (filter (== head b) b):[[4,4]]
[[5,5,5],[4,4]]
```

Something is going over my head.  Could someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: `pack` is same as `group` from `Data.List`

Comment: Correct, I am just working through solving some exercises.   I wanted to do it w/o only renaming the function.

Comment: `group` groups only consecutive duplicates, fyi.

Comment: Thank you for the correction of my incorrect correction @kqr

Comment: @kqr Isn't that what pack is doing here?

Comment: @Satvik yes. I was correcting kealist. I'm sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I deleted my incorrect comment, so it caused the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seventh line is a little weird:

```
((filter (== head ys) ys):xs) (filter (/= head ys) ys)
```

What it says is:

1. Take the function given by

   ```
   ((filter (== head ys) ys):xs)
   ```
2. and call it with the argument

   ```
   (filter (/= head ys) ys)
   ```

which is probably not at all what you intended. This becomes more clear if you replace the expressions with names, like the following equivalent expression:

```
let func = ((filter (== head ys) ys):xs)
    arg  = (filter (/= head ys) ys)
in  func arg
```

Did you miss to put something between the two expressions? Keep in mind that `arg` in this case is `[a]` while `func` is `[[a]]`. I think you meant to say

```
func : [arg]
```

but I'm not sure, because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes, I forgot to recursively call pack'.  It was a case of causing myself frustration....sigh.  Maybe I should delete the question

Answer (score 1):

The expression `pack' xs ys = ((filter (== head ys) ys):xs) (filter (/= head ys) ys)` contains the error.  The subexpression `((filter (== head ys) ys):xs)` is being used as a function with `(filter (/= head ys) ys)` as its argument.  However, `((filter (== head ys) ys):xs)` has type `[[a]]`, since `filter (== head ys) ys` returns a value of type `[a]`, and it is appended onto the front of `xs`, which is of type `[[a]]`.

What is the expected return value for `pack'`?  Could you provide an example that would demonstrate its behavior?